# Asp.Net: How to allow access to a page to intranet user and deny for extranet users?

Tags: asp.net, authentication, authorization

I have an app with two pages: pagein.aspx and pageout.aspx. Pagein.aspx must be accessible ONLY to intranet users of my company, but pageout.aspx must be accessible to extranet users (world). My last option is to use the authorization (user and password), but I prefer to use the logic I described. Is this possible in asp.net? If yes, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this via web.config

```
<location path="Pagein.aspx"> 
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" allow role="YourDomain\Domain Users" />
          <deny users="*" />
         </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
<location path="PageOut.aspx"> 
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
          <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Answer (score 1):

The simpler solution is to have two websites (two virtual directories), in one enable windows authentication: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647405.aspx

In the other, use ASP.NET membership, or leave it public and accessible by anonymous users.

If you need both in the same application, then use the various authorization techniques to require authorization for some pages and leave other pages open to the public.